# php data inserting issue UTF8 working properly on local host

Tags: php, mysql

Currently i am working on storing Arabic text in MySQL db table using php. but it store text in this **????????** format, interesting things is that same code is working properly on local machine but issue is occurred on live server table field is set to **CHARSET=utf8**

```
function con(){
    $link = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");    
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    printf("Initial character set: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($link));

    /* change character set to utf8 */
    if (!mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8")) {
        printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
        exit();
    } else {
        printf("Current character set: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($link));
    }

    return $link;
}

function finsert() {
    $vReturn = false;
    $rQuery = "INSERT INTO tblname(`c1`, `c2`) VALUES (v1, v2)";
    $link = con();
    if (mysqli_query($link, $rQuery)) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo mysqli_error($link);
    }
}

finsert();
```

Comment: So what do those `printf` outputs give you? What encoding is the data really sent in to/from the browser?

Comment: INSERT INTO tbl(`id`, `text`) VALUES (801, 'ھے'); this is the out put of the query print, but it does not storing in this format, furthermore if i execute directly on table which is executed successfully and store text in correct format

Comment: your problem solved or not

Comment: Not yet, still issue persist